# URLSession in swift 4 without completion handler

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession

can anyone tell me what all URLSession delegate methods should me implemented along with an example in swift 4.

**I DO NOT WANT TO USE COMPLETION HANDLER.**

My app is in objective c, and i am converting it in swift.
earlier it uses NSURLConnection which is now deprecated.
So it's little confusing for me to use URLSession.

Thanks!

EDIT:
I am using something like

```
let defaultSession = URLSession(configuration: defaultSessionConfiguration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    let sessionTask = defaultSession.dataTask(with: requests)
    sessionTask.resume()
```

Now i want to implement methods which will handle senarios when it receives response, data or error.

I am looking for equivalent of

```
func connection(_ connection: NSURLConnection, didReceive data: Data){}

func connection(_ connection: NSURLConnection, didFailWithError error: Error){}

func connection(_ connection: NSURLConnection, canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace protectionSpace: URLProtectionSpace) -> Bool {
    return protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust
}

func connection(_ connection: NSURLConnection, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge) {
        if (challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust) {
            if let aTrust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust {
                challenge.sender?.use(URLCredential(trust: aTrust), for: challenge)
            }
        }
        challenge.sender?.continueWithoutCredential(for: challenge)
    }
```

Comment: Without completion handler how would you check request completion?

Comment: Take a look here: https://www.raywenderlich.com/158106/urlsession-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: What is the reason for not using completion handlers??

Comment: @Rob I have done few edits in the question.

Comment: See [`didReceive`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiondatadelegate/1411528-urlsession), [`didCompleteWithError`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiontaskdelegate/1411610-urlsession), [`didReceive challenge`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiondelegate/1409308-urlsession), [task `didReceive` challenge](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiontaskdelegate/1411595-urlsession).